# How can I apply a Hough Transform to my image, with the final goal of detecting a rectangle?

Tags: java, image, opencv, hough-transform

I've been trying to get my Hough transform to modify the images below my code. So far I have run a RGB2GRAY transform and a Canny Edge detection function on the image. My end goal is to detect the location of the VIN sticker on images similar to the one below.

I've tried to use a Hough transform but I don't think it is implemented correctly, because it has no effect on the output image.

The part that I'm most confused about currently is what the "lines" variable in the HoughLinesP function actually does.

My foremost question: How can I apply the results of the Hough transform to my output image?

My secondary question: After the Hough transform has been applied, what would be my next step to identifying the VIN sticker's location?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class VinDetector {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        File input = new File("image.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);  

        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Mat sourceImg = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        sourceImg.put(0, 0, data);

        Mat destImage = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceImg, destImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        Imgproc.Canny(destImage, destImage, 50, 100);
        Imgproc.threshold(destImage, destImage, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        Mat lines = new Mat();
        int threshold = 50; // minimum number of intersections to detect a line 
        int minLineSize = 25; // minimum number of points that can be considered a line
        int lineGap = 10; // maxmimum number of points between two points to be still considered the same line
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(destImage, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);

        byte[] data1 = new byte[destImage.rows() * destImage.cols() * (int)(destImage.elemSize())];
        destImage.get(0, 0, data1);
        BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(destImage.cols(),destImage.rows(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        image1.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, destImage.cols(), destImage.rows(), data1);

        File ouptut = new File("image TEST.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", ouptut);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

[image: This image of a VIN on a car].
[image: this].

Comment: You need to run Hough on the grayscale image (before canny)

Comment: try line segment detector instead of canny